# Firebase Notifcation [IOS] not working when app is in background

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

Using:

- xcode 10.3
- firebase plugin ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm )
- cordova version 8.1.2

The xcode console shows:

- app enters background
- Set state background
- Disconnected from FCM

What do I have:

- Push notification enable on the app(on https://developer.apple.com/)
- All the keys/Certificates

I get the token identifier on the iphone, so I suppose it's working but I'm not sure since when you get a notification with the app opened it does show the notification ( Also if someone knows how to fix it, I would appreciate it) but my question is how to stop from disconnecting the FCM plugin when the app goes to background.

Only code I have

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN] = 'Ligação desconhecida';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI] = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G] = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G] = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G] = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL] = 'Cell generic connection';
            states[Connection.NONE] = 'Sem ligação a internet';

            if (states[networkState] === states[Connection.NONE]) {
                alert("A aplicação necessida de internet para funcionar correctamente");
            }
        }

        FCMPlugin.getToken(function (token) {
            myToken = token;
            alert(token);
        }, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Did you enable background mode for your app in xcode?

Comment: @Eric I enabled Background fetch and remote notifications in xcode